# someone help me understand what is constant factor of a computer and what is mean by "faster computer have low constant factor"

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, constants, big-o

[udemy course for DSA for python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBaHd.png)

i'm learning DSA and i can't able to under what he meant by faster computer have low constant factor,i know that constant factor means (correct me if i'm wrong,O(6n) 6 is constant because no matter how many input we give the 6 remains the same)but how faster PC have low constant factor?

(sorry it might be a simple question,but i'm new to programming,i did some research i just don't understand properly)

Answer (score 2):

A faster computer can perform a "unit of work" faster than a slower one. If your computer can do literally everything twice as fast as some other computer, the "`6n`" work can be done in "`3n`" instead. The big-O of `O(n)` hasn't changed (because constant factors don't affect it), but it's faster at doing the same amount of work, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

When we give the time complexity of an algorithm, we use big-O notation.  We might say, for example, that the algorithm takes O(f(n)) time to process an input of size n in the worst case.

Formally, this means that if T(n) is the *actual* time that some implementation of the algorithm takes, then T(n) <= C*f(n), for some constant C, for all sufficiently large n.

This statement is true for *all* implementations of the algorithm. That's why we use big-O notation in the first place.  On faster computers, though, the algorithm will take less time.  That corresponds to a smaller constant factor C.